# Replacing Divs with Elements Defined in External Files

Tags: html, angularjs

Suppose I have

```
<div>
    <div id="stuff">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way for me to put the contents of `<div id="stuff">` into a file -- say `stuff.html` -- and then replace the code above with something the like following:

```
<div>
    <stuff.html>
</div>
```

EDIT: I preferred angularjs, but was open to jQuery solutions as well.  I should have been clearer from the outside rather than just leaving a dangling angular tag.

Comment: You should clearify if you are indeed using AngularJS, or any other templating framework. If so you really need to use that framework to be loading templates.

Answer (score 1):

Using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("stuff.html"); 
    });
</script>
```

Then, later on in your code:

```
<body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't use jquery when Angular by itself provides the functionality needed.

Comment: I may have been too quick on the 'no jquery' comment. The question is labeled as AngularJS but no mention of in the actual question.

Comment: @Enzey the OP says nowhere that he can only use [tag:angular].

Comment: but if Angular is being used then using JQuery to load DOM is a nightmare. It will load the DOM outside of the frameworks life-cycle and thus will not be processed by it.

Answer (score 1):

Angular provides template loading via `ng-include`.

In your case you could do the following:

```
<div>
    <div ng-include="'stuff.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Do node the double quoted string. Without the double quotes the directive will try to resolve the value from the current scope.

Comment: Are you able to include <script> and <style> tags within the `stuff.html` (so it can be a fully contained system)?

Comment: no, these would need to be HTML fragments, anything below a <body> tag. You could load the scripts through other means but if you are going to be loading a lot of <script> and <style> tags dynamically you would be creating a bit of DOM soup. Making it more likely of getting into a situation where loading one script or style breaks the rest of the app but since they are dynamically loaded that situation does not always exist, making for a debugging nightmare.

Comment: you can, but you shouldn't :). What Enzey says: it will be a mess...Why don't you use routing for this btw: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute